# How to call a variable from inside a function within a class?

Tags: python

I want to call a variable created in a function (func) that is also in a class (A). Below is a very basic version of what I want to accomplish in my larger code. I am fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        self.number =  1

print(A.number)
```

Comment: I agree with @AyoubBenayache ,you should check out guides for OOP on Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about static var : (copy/paste)

ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/

You can run the code there to understand more

#### Class or Static Variables in Python

Class or static variables are shared by all objects. Instance or non-static variables are different for different objects (every object has a copy of it).
For example, let a Computer Science Student be represented by class CSStudent. The class may have a static variable whose value is “cse” for all objects. And class may also have non-static members like name and roll.

In C++ and Java, we can use static keyword to make a variable as class variable. The variables which don’t have preceding static keyword are instance variables. See this for Java example and this for C++ example.

The Python approach is simple, it doesn’t require a static keyword. All variables which are assigned a value in class declaration are class variables. And variables which are assigned values inside class methods are instance variables.

```
# Python program to show that the variables with a value  
# assigned in class declaration, are class variables 
  
# Class for Computer Science Student 
class CSStudent: 
    stream = 'cse'                  # Class Variable 
    def __init__(self,name,roll): 
        self.name = name            # Instance Variable 
        self.roll = roll            # Instance Variable 
  
# Objects of CSStudent class 
a = CSStudent('Geek', 1) 
b = CSStudent('Nerd', 2) 
  
print(a.stream)  # prints "cse" 
print(b.stream)  # prints "cse" 
print(a.name)    # prints "Geek" 
print(b.name)    # prints "Nerd" 
print(a.roll)    # prints "1" 
print(b.roll)    # prints "2" 
  
# Class variables can be accessed using class 
# name also 
print(CSStudent.stream) # prints "cse"
CSStudent.stream = "foo"
print(a.stream)         # prints "foo" (this variable litterally is CSStudent.stream)
```